# How to make a color darker in Java

Tags: java, colors

I am making a drawing tool in java, but the orange is seems a bit too light.
Where to put the color name at the function `public Color darker()`?

```java
      public void clear() {
        g2.setPaint(Color.white);
        // draw white on entire draw area to clear
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
      }

      public void red() {
        // apply red color on g2 context
        g2.setPaint(Color.red);
      }

      public void black() {
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
      }

      public void magenta() {
        g2.setPaint(Color.magenta);
      }

      public void green() {
        g2.setPaint(Color.green);
      }

      public void blue() {
        g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
      }
      public void yellow() {
        g2.setPaint(Color.yellow);
      }
      public void orange() {
        g2.setPaint(Color.orange.darker);
      }
    }
```

Please tell me what to write to make the orange darker.

Comment: `color = color.darker();`, maybe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```
Color.ORANGE.darker()
```

or

```
Color.orange.darker()
```

Also, if you still think that it is not dark enough, you can even do:

```
Color.orange.darker().darker().darker().darker().darker() // as many times as you want!
```

Also, the default orange color, as defined in the class is:

```
new Color(255, 200, 0)
```

If you want, you may do something with those numbers!

In your code, change this line:

```
g2.setPaint(Color.orange.darker);
```

to

```
g2.setPaint(Color.orange.darker()); // darker ain't a var, it is a method.
```

And,

```
drawArea.orange.darker();
```

to

```
 drawArea.orange(); //You cannot call darker() on void!
```

Comment: The critical point is that `darker()` returns a new color: it doesn't make `Color.ORANGE` darker. So these statements are effectively no-ops - you need to do something with the result.

Comment: @AndyTurner, it is not what you think it is! (Sorry!) It is like - `setBackground(Color.orange.darker());`

Comment: Right. So... you're doing something with the result if you pass it to `setBackground`. Sounds a lot like what I said.

Comment: If you think it is that, then remove the semicolons from each single line, because they imply what Andy said (and your incorrect comment (before the edit) also showed that).

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I created:

```
public static int darker (int color, float factor) {
    int a = Color.Orange( color );


    return Color.argb( a,
            Math.max( (int)(r * factor), 0 ));
}
```

Comment: For the [`java.awt.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class, `Color.Orange` isn't a method, `Color.argb` isn't a method, `r` isn't defined. If you're referring to some other `Color` class, please say what that class is.